# How do I install a specific version of a git commit library in Linux?

Tags: linux

How to install a specific version of git commit in Linux? When any program requests for the library it should take from the installation.

Eg:
The following version of wiringPi is required by one of my c++ program.

```
git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
Version: 5edd177112c99416f68ba3e8c6c4db6ed942e796
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C or make?

Comment: See [git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs); BTW, `git` is so useful that you need to know a bit of it

Comment: The sentence "install a specific version of git commit in Linux" makes no logical sense. The best way to get a helpful answer on stackoverflow is to ask a question that can be understood. If you want to check out a specific commit from a git repository, then after "git clone" simply check out that commit: "git checkout <hash>".

Comment: The specific git commit has to be used in a C/C++ program,m I hope there will be an alternative solution by using makefile

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a checkout statement after you clone?

Eg:

```
git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
git checkout 5edd177112c99416f68ba3e8c6c4db6ed942e796
```

Then you type the build and installation commands - if you want everything to use it, it probably needs to go in the default location. For the package you're looking at the documentation says it's:

```
./build
```

If you already have a version from a package manager (like `apt` you should remove that first - the `README.md` from the package you linked explains how to do this)

Comment: I want to know about the content of ./build ?